# Chrome - Extension v3 code: No matching signature

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome-extension

In my Chrome v3 extention app I have changed chrome.**tabs**.executeScript to chrome.**scripting**.executeScript. Getting "No matching signature", Tried to fix it but I was unable.

Please help me here to solve the error..!

**Manifest:**

```
{
  "name": "OkBot",
  "description": "OkBot is used as a Personal Asistant.",
  "version": "1.1",
  "manifest_version": 3,
  "content_security_policy": {
    "extension_pages": "script-src 'self'; object-src 'self'"
  },
  "minimum_chrome_version": "88",
  "offline_enabled": false,
  "icons": {
    "48": "web/images/icon_48.png",
    "128": "web/images/icon_128.png"
  },
  "action": {
    "default_icon": {
      "19": "web/images/icon_19.png",
      "38": "web/images/icon_38.png"
    },
    "default_title": "OkBot",
    "default_popup": "popup.html"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "idle",
    "power",
    "management",
    "storage",
    "tabs",
    "activeTab",
    "topSites",
    "scripting"
  ],
  "host_permissions": [
    "*://*/*",
    "<all_urls>"
  ],
  "optional_permissions":[
  ],
  "options_page": "options.html",
  "background":{
    "service_worker":"web/js/background.js"
  },
  "content_scripts": [
    {
      "js": ["web/js/content_script.js"],
      "matches": ["<all_urls>", "*://*/*"]
    }
  ]
}
```

**OkBot.js Script:**

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "web/js/storage.js"}, function() {
    if(chrome.runtime.lastError) 
        chrome.scripting.executeScript(tabs[0].id, {file: "web/js/content.js"}, function() {
            if(chrome.runtime.lastError) {
                console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
            }
            else
            {
                setTimeout(function(){ 
                    send_to_content(obj); // Then call send_to_content(obj) again after content.js injected
            }, 300);
        }
    });
});
```

**Error handling response**: TypeError: Error in invocation of scripting.executeScript(scripting.ScriptInjection injection, optional function callback): No matching signature.

Comment: Perhaps `chrome.scripting.executeScript({target: tabs[0].id, file: "web/js/storage.js"}`, ...`?

Comment: @DillGates - Do you know what "No matching signature" means?

Comment: @Thomas Mueller No, I'm a beginner for Chrome extention. but, Tried to google to understand it. But, I couldn't.

Comment: See the documentation: there's no `file` parameter. There is `files`, which is an array e.g. `files: ['foo.js']`

Comment: Docs of valid scriptinjection properties are [here](https://developer.chrome.com/docs/extensions/reference/scripting/#type-ScriptInjection)

Comment: I have resolved it, Thanks all for the suggestions. & Sorry for asking this silly question.

Answer (score 1):

I fixed with the right syntax as the v3 doc. Thanks for all the suggestions.

```
chrome.scripting.executeScript(
{
    target: {tabId: active_tab, allFrames: true},
    files: ['web/js/storage.js'],
}, function() {
        if (chrome.runtime.lastError) {
            console.error(chrome.runtime.lastError.message);
        }
        else
        {
            setTimeout(function(){ 
                send_to_content(obj); //Call send_to_content(obj) after content.js injected
            }, 300);
        }
    });
```